# How to store data in an attribute and then parse on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My end goal is to be able to send:

```
$('[data-track]').live('click', function () {
    mpmetrics.track("Share", {'method': 'twitter'});
});
```

My question is how I can store the Share, method, twitter in the data-bind attribute so that they are dynamic and I can change the variables on any data-track attribute in my app.

```
<a data-track="XXXXXX" href="#">Tweet</a>
```

For XXXXXX, how can I set the 3 variables and then parse them in the data-track binding?

Thanks

Comment: Update. my app will have 100s od data-track attributes and they will all have different values which is why I want a way to define data-track in a way where the live binding can parse and send out dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a data-track="Share,method,twitter" href="#">
```

Then...

```
var dataTrack = $(this).data('track').split(','); // split by comma

var action    = dataTrack[0];
var values    = {};
values[dataTrack[1]] = dataTrack[2];

mpmetrics.track(action, values);
```

Comment: Thanks, I like where this is headed. So how do I take paramsArray and get mpmetrics.track("Share", {'method': 'twitter'}); Can you update your question to get marked as the answer ? Thanks

Comment: might be better to use commas to delimit that way params can include spaces right?

Comment: Updated with values inserted. Good call on the commas, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: Strange, this gives a 38Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Right after the `var params` line, add `console.log(params);` and let me know what it outputs.

Comment: Seems to work great, maybe it MixPanels track method. here is what I get? ["Share", "method", "twitter"]

Comment: Weird. Try replacing each array value with a string to see which the culprit is.

Comment: it's params[1], changing to mpmetrics.track(params[0], {"params[1]": params[2]}); works fine. Reserved JS word?

Comment: Is there a way to put it in "" quotes and evaluate inside?

Comment: Made some minor changes above - any difference?

Comment: interesting. Still errors though - 38Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Weird thing... I didn't have any idea there would be a quirk with naming object properties with array reference. I'm going to have to do some reading on that. lol

Answer (score 2):

You can store any kind of value via [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data). Store the three values as a series of key/value pairs in an object:

```
$('a').data('track', { key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' });
```

Fetch it later with

```
$('a').data('track');
```

Alternatively, just define them as three data attributes:

```
<a data-track="XXXXXX" data-key1="value1" data-key2="value2" href="#">Tweet</a>
```

And access them via `.data()`:

```
$('a[data-track]').click(function () {
  var $key1 = $(this).data('key1');
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I would like to store them in the links or buttons data-track attribute as there will be a lot and I don't want all this defined in JS?

Comment: Thanks but I would like to stick to one attribute to keep it cleaner. Is there a way I can define a JSON object in the data-track and then parse and send that out in the binding click... I need this to be very reusable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be working:

```
<a id="btn" href="#" data='{"method":"twitter","action":"Share"}'>Test</a>

$('#btn').click(function(){
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).attr('data'));
});
```

Comment: You can access your properties using
`mpmetrics.track(data.action, {'method': data.method});`

Comment: I used `$(this).attr('data') and not $(this).data('data')` ;-)

Comment: You are right, my bad, I thought it would work the same, [apparently not](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/ufgQb/). However, I am not that fond of using invalid DOM attributes. :)